# »Wer nicht vorwärts geht, der kommt zurücke«. Woher kommt das »e«?

Tags: word-usage, difference, quotes

> Wer nicht vorwärts geht, der kommt zurücke.

Ich habe diese Zitate von Goethe gesehen und ich wollte fragen, warum der Buchstabe »**e**« am Ende des Wortes »**zurücke**« steht?
Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »zurück« und »zurück**e**«?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Satz ist ein Zitat aus Goethes [*Hermann und Dorothea*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_und_Dorothea). Es steht im dritten Gesang *Thalia*. Den Volltext kann man [im Projekt Gutenberg](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/hermann-und-dorothea-3634/4) online lesen.

Ich habe nicht das Ganze gelesen, aber den Ausschnitt der näheren Umgebung. Es fällt auf, dass alles im Hexameter gehalten ist, wobei das Versmaß weder streng in Trochäen noch streng in Daktylen gehalten ist – zumindest für mich als Nichtgermanist. Das alleine würde ein Fugen-*e* zur Versmaßanpassung nicht nötig erscheinen lassen. Dennoch wird das Werk ein *Lied* genannt, und wird aus *Gesängen* aufgebaut, was daraus schließen lassen könnte, dass Goethe irgendeine Melodie im Hinterkopf hätte, an die der Sprechrhythmus angepasst werden müsste – oder sonstige Wünsche an den Rhythmus hatte.

Auf jeden Fall ist das zusätzliche *e* völlig überflüssig und lässt sich höchstens über rhythmische Überlegungen erklären. In dem benachbarten Gesang *Euterpe* taucht *zurück* auch folgerichtig ohne Versmaß-*e* auf – was belegt, dass es nicht eine antiquierte Form des Wortes ist.

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort *zurück* ist entstanden aus der Verbindung der Präposition *zu* mit dem Substantiv *Rücken*. Das End-*n* in *Rücken* ist dabei eine relativ junge Entwicklung, und so lautete die mittelhochdeutsche Vorgängerform *ze rucke*. Im Neuhochdeutschen ist dies als *zurück* und *zurücke* angekommen, wobei sich letztlich die apokopierte Form *zurück* durchgesetzt hat. Diese Entwicklung hat sich jedoch bis ins 19. Jahrhundert hingezogen. (Zur Wortgeschichte siehe das DWB s.v. [*zurück*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=32,678,1) und s.v. [*Rücken*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=14,1346,56).)

Zu Goethes Zeit war *zurücke* bereits stark auf dem Rückzug, aber noch nicht so ungewöhnlich wie heute. Das DWB schreibt

> nach der durchführung der worteinung ist *zurücke* nur noch stilvariante von *zurück*, die aus metrischen gründen und überhaupt als literarische form gebraucht wird

und führt eine Reihe von Belegen aus dem 18. und 19. Jahrhundert an, darunter weitere Stellen bei Goethe, auch in Prosa.

Es gibt auch einen spezifischen metrischen Grund, warum Goethe gerade hier *zurücke* gewählt haben dürfte: Andernfalls wäre der fünfte Fuß in diesem Hexameter ein Spondeus/Trochäus geworden (und der Vers somit ein *versus spondiacus*); obendrein hätte der ganze Vers dann nur aus zweisilbigen Füßen bestanden (sogenannter *Holospondeus*). Beides wird bereits bei den Dichtern der griechisch-römischen Antike möglichst vermieden, an der Goethe sich orientiert – der Hexameter ist ja ein antikes Versmaß, das in der deutschen Literatur vor der Klassik keine Tradition hatte. (Zum Hexameter allgemein siehe [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexameter).)

Hier noch der vollständige Vers aus [*Hermann und Dorothea*](http://resolver.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/SBB0000341600000054) mit Betonungsschema:

> Wer nicht vorwärts geht, der kommt zurücke! So bleibt es.
>   x́x x́x x́x x́x x́xx x́x